# modifying json from php array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array where i fetch from **php** with variable `$allresults` :

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 16/03/2018
        [1] => Friday
        [2] => 21.00
        [3] => Friendly Match
        [4] => Italy vs France
        [5] => Truesports HD
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 17/03/2018
        [1] => Saturday
        [2] => 15.30
        [3] => Friendly Match
        [4] => Italy vs Pakistan
        [5] => Truesports HD
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 17/03/2018
        [1] => Saturday
        [2] => 19.00
        [3] => Friendly Match
        [4] => Spain vs USA
        [5] => Truesports
    )
)
```

I have to convert it into json for other production use, so i use `json_encode()` with this code below

```
echo json_encode($allresults, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

and the result become

```
[
    "16\/03\/2018",
    "Friday",
    "21.00",
    "Friendly Match",
    "Italy vs France",
    "Truesports HD"
],
[
    "17\/03\/2018",
    "Saturday",
    "15.30",
    "Friendly Match",
    "Italy vs Pakistan",
    "Truesports HD"
],
[
    "17\/03\/2018",
    "Saturday",
    "19.00",
    "Friendly Match",
    "Spain vs USA",
    "Truesports"
]
```

My point is how can i change this into something like this in my json.

```
[
    "date":"17\/03\/2018",
    "day":"Saturday",
    "time":"19.00",
    "type":"Friendly Match",
    "value":"Spain vs USA",
    "tv":"Truesports"
]
```

Should i change this from php array or i could change this from json file directly?

Comment: Your expected output is not a valid json. And where are the other information go?

Comment: Update array key values before encoding into json

Comment: [JSON](http://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure (usually an array or an object). It is used to transfer the data between computers. At the destination it is decoded to get back the original data structure. It is not easily editable and it was not designed to be editable. Read about PHP [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), generate the array you need then [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) it.

Comment: indeed i need to modify it from php.. thanks for all the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update your array with key. Or second option is you can create new array with your expected output key:

```
$array = Array
(
"1" => Array
    (
        "0" => "16/03/2018",
        "1" => "Friday",
        "2" => "21.00",
        "3" => "Friendly Match",
        "4" => "Italy vs France",
        "5" => "Truesports HD",
    ),
"2" => Array
    (
        "0" => "17/03/2018",
        "1" => "Saturday",
        "2" => "15.30",
        "3" => "Friendly Match",
        "4" => "Italy vs Pakistan",
        "5" => "Truesports HD",
    ),

"3" => Array
    (
        "0" => "17/03/2018",
        "1" => "Saturday",
        "2" => "19.00",
        "3" => "Friendly Match",
        "4" => "Spain vs USA",
        "5" => "Truesports"
    )
);
$array_keys= array("date","day","time","type","value","tv");
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $tmp_array = array();
  foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
    if(isset($array_keys[$key1]))
        $tmp_array[$array_keys[$key1]] = $value1;
  }
  $new_array[] =$tmp_array;
}

echo json_encode($new_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/ah0ef)

Comment: thanks it works, but there is a php error on this line         $tmp_array[$array_keys[$key1]] = $value1;

error code  Undefined offset: 6 

other than that it works great

Comment: ah i figured it out as i have more than 6 subarrays in another arrays..thank you

Comment: i cant upvote, but i have selected the answer thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
$field = array("date","day","time","type","value","tv");

echo "<pre>";

foreach($yourArr as $value){

    $j = 0;

    foreach($value as $arrVal){
        //Get Field Name
        $fieldKey = $field[$j];

        $newArr[$fieldKey] = $arrVal;

        $j++;
    }
    $finalArr[] = $newArr;
}
print_r($finalArr);
```

Comment: thanks it works great as answer above but i'm getting same php error for this line             $fieldKey = $field[$j];

getting   Undefined offset: 6

Comment: ah i figured it out as i have more than 6 subarrays in another arrays

Answer (score 0):

I used `array_combine()` function -  Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values

```
$array = array
(
"1" => array
    (
        "0" => "16/03/2018",
        "1" => "Friday",
        "2" => "21.00",
        "3" => "Friendly Match",
        "4" => "Italy vs France",
        "5" => "Truesports HD",
    ),
"2" => array
    (
        "0" => "17/03/2018",
        "1" => "Saturday",
        "2" => "15.30",
        "3" => "Friendly Match",
        "4" => "Italy vs Pakistan",
        "5" => "Truesports HD",
    ),

"3" => array
    (
        "0" => "17/03/2018",
        "1" => "Saturday",
        "2" => "19.00",
        "3" => "Friendly Match",
        "4" => "Spain vs USA",
        "5" => "Truesports"
    )
);
$array_keys= array("date","day","time","type","value","tv");
$newArray=array();
foreach($array as $subArr){
    $newArray[] = array_combine($array_keys,$subArr);
}
echo json_encode($newArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/YfRbA)